# Mock array of objects using Jest

Tags: typescript, mocking, jestjs, jest-preset-angular

I am trying to write a unit test with Jest for a service in angular app and I have a question about how to mock a data. As part of my mock data I need to mock `Array<App>` which has an interface like this

```js
        interface App  {
            Color: string;
            Id: string;
            Size: TileSize;
            Text: string;
            Title: string;
            Url: string;
        }
```

so I tried to mock the data like this in my test file:

```js
    const Apps: Array<App> = [
            {
                'Id': 'Chat',
                'Text': 'Chat',
                'Title': 'Go to your chat',
                'Url': 'https://chat.com'
            },
            {
                'Id': 'Mail',
                'Text': 'Mail',
                'Title': 'Go to your Mail',
                'Url': 'https://mail.com'
            }
        ];
    
    MockConfigParserService.mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
                parse: () => {
                    return {
                        workloads
                    };
                }
            };
        });
```

My test fails running the service that I am testing by throwing this error

```
 Unhandled Promise rejection: workloads.slice is not a function ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: workloads.slice is not a function
```

at this line of code in service code (the service works fine outside of test): `return this.appsPromise.then(apps => [...apps]);`

how should I change mock data for array of apps so it doesn't throw this error?
Thanks a lot in davance

Comment: Can you post your `MockConfigParserService` code? Which method do you want to test?

Comment: What does `workloads` look like? Seems like it is not an array, but the Service call expects an array.